# WordPress Custom Post Type Pagination Issue

Tags: wordpress, pagination

Both me and my friend are completely bamboozled as to whats going on here. The quest is to have standard pagination linking from one post to the next. We can see the pages going from page/2/, page/3/ etc but the content does not change.

Here is what we've got in the custom template.

```
 <?php
 /**
 * The Template for displaying all single posts.
 *
 * Template Name: Portfolio
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Boilerplate
 * @since Boilerplate 1.0
 */

 get_header();

 // Enable Pagination
 $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

 $args = array(
 'post_type' => array(
 'portfolio'
 ),
 'orderby' => 'date',
 'posts_per_page' => 1,
 'paged'=>$paged
 );

 $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

 while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 

 ?>

 <article id="item<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('post portfolio'); ?>>
   <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
   <div>
     <?php the_content(); ?>
   </div>
 </article>

 <?php endwhile; ?>
     <?php next_posts_link('« Older Entries') ?>
     <?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries »') ?>
 <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

 <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And in the bottom of the functions.php lives some custom post type script...

```
// Custom Post Type

function foggin_Portfolio() {
$labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Portfolio', 'post type general name' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Portfolio', 'post type singular name' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Item' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit item' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Item' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All Items' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Item' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search items' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No item' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No items found in the Trash' ),
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => 'Portfolio'
);
$args = array(
    'labels'        => $labels,
    'description'   => 'Holds portfolio items and portfolio specific data',
    'public'        => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'rewrite'       => array('slug'=>'','with_front'=>false),
    'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'taxonomies'),
    'taxonomies'    => array('post_tag'),
    'has_archive'   => true,
);
register_post_type( 'portfolio', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'foggin_Portfolio' );

function portfolio_messages( $messages ) {
    global $post, $post_ID;
    $messages['portfolio'] = array(
        0 => '',
        1 => sprintf( __('Portfolio item updated. <a href="%s">View item</a>'), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
        2 => __('Custom field updated.'),
        3 => __('Custom field deleted.'),
        4 => __('Product updated.'),
        5 => isset($_GET['revision']) ? sprintf( __('Portfolio item restored to revision from %s'), wp_post_revision_title( (int) $_GET['revision'], false ) ) : false,
        6 => sprintf( __('Portfolio item published. <a href="%s">View item</a>'), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
        7 => __('Portfolio item saved.'),
        8 => sprintf( __('Portfolio item submitted. <a target="_blank" href="%s">Preview item</a>'), esc_url( add_query_arg( 'preview', 'true', get_permalink($post_ID) ) ) ),
        9 => sprintf( __('Portfolio item scheduled for: <strong>%1$s</strong>. <a target="_blank" href="%2$s">Preview item</a>'), date_i18n( __( 'M j, Y @ G:i' ), strtotime( $post->post_date ) ), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
        10 => sprintf( __('Portfolio item draft updated. <a target="_blank" href="%s">Preview item</a>'), esc_url( add_query_arg( 'preview', 'true', get_permalink($post_ID) ) ) ),
        );
        return $messages;
    }

    add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', 'portfolio_messages' );


    function portfolio_taxonomies() {
        $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Categories' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Categories' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Category' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Category' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Category' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Category' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Categories' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'portfolio_category', 'portfolio', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'portfolio_taxonomies', 0 );

?>
```

Thoughts, ideas, advice would be really helpful I think it's fair to say we're both stumped on this.

Answer (score 0):

It may sound silly, but reset your permalinks to default, then back to your desired format. The .htaccess file needs to be rewritten after the post types have been added into functions.php

Your action for **rewrite** option being set to *false* could be causing an issue as well. If WP isn't clear on rewriting yourdomain.com/page/2/ so having the rewrite to true makes it yourdomain.com/portfolio/page/2/

Everything else seems to be in order with your query.